# SQL Joins In Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

```
User.where(created_at: "2015-08-02").joins(:likes).count
```

What does this exactly mean in Rails?
Specifically compared to `User.where(created_at: "2015-08-02").count` (without joins)

Please translate it to English. Thanks.

Comment: it will make a join query with `likes`. so what it does is.
`select users inner join likes on the likes.user_id = user.id` and select those likes which are linked to the user. and then fetch those users whose `created_at` is "2015-08-02"

Comment: @Athar then it would mean "Count 'likes' that are linked to the users created in 2015/08/2" in English, right?

Comment: Fire this in your Rails console, and see what it is showing. That's the best way to understand this

Comment: no it will count user. it is just joining to likes and do nothing on likes

Comment: What I specifially wonder is it counts "likes" or "users".

Comment: @ZHH it counts the users and also displays the like for that users in the output

Comment: run this `User.where(created_at: "2015-08-02").joins(:likes).count.to_sql` in `rails console` it will show you the query

Comment: Then, "Count users who are linked with 'likes' and joined 8/2" ?

Comment: yes. you can also confirm the difference by running two queries. like this `User.where(created_at: "2015-08-02").joins(:likes).count` and `User.where(created_at: "2015-08-02").count` one with join and other without join and you can see the difference.

Comment: When interpreting this, it's important to now that the `joins` member in Rails does an `INNER` join on the primary key. With an `INNER` join, the results only contain records that have a non-null, matching primary key. So, it will only *count* (not *show*) user records created on 8/2/2015 that have associated likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first one joined 2 tables (`likes` and `users`) and count the entries in the `users` table which have an entry in the `likes` table. the other one count all `users` and don't care about entries in the `likes` table

so if you have 100 users, then both gives you count 100.
if you have 100 users, and 90 users have a like, then your first gives you ccount of 90 and your second query gives you count of 100.